# How to wrap an existing c# library into a new namespace

Tags: c#

How would I wrap an existing library into my own namespace, so when the time comes I can replace it with my own implementation?

There is no simple way of aliasing the namespace or the types, at least I did not find a simple way to do this.

Is there a possibility of creating some kind of alias or renaming the existing one in a simple way?

Comment: Perhaps [`extern alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since .NET 6 you can define a global alias for the root namespace (see the [`global` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier) section of the [`using` directive docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)):

In any file (usually I prefer to have dedicated one for such things):

```cs
global using MyALias = ClassLibraryRootNamespace;
```

or in the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Using Alias="MyALias" Include="ClassLibraryRootNamespace"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Another option worth looking is [`extern alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias).

Note that usability of such approach can vary based on what you are actually using from the library - to "seamlessly" substitute later you will need to repeat the class structure and naming in your new implementation.

Personally I would consider decorating (see the [correspondingly named pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)) the library usage and wrapping it in some more generic/suitable API so the implementation can be easily changed later.

Comment: Is there a possibility to custom wrap the library using decorators or similar with a "zero cost" method? So the naming might be more generic/suitable but the underlying logic is used without any overhead. In the same way a type alias would work if it's resolved at compiletime.

Comment: @SanBen I doubt that. But wrapping cost if any would be minimal in majority of scenarios.